# Size of an http call with window.performance

Tags: javascript

I currently saving the duration of some httpCall to analyse performance of my web application. I use **window.performance.getEntries()** and get only the calls I need.

All is working perfecly, but I want to get the size of this saved call. This was possible using window.performance ?

Answer (score 0):

For ones who want to do the same thing than me, I found a documentation speaking about that in MDN :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/encodedBodySize

The methods exists, but browsers do not yet implemented it.

Here the sample of code from MDN :

```
function log_sizes(perfEntry){
  // Check for support of the PerformanceEntry.*size properties and print their values
  // if supported.
  if ("decodedBodySize" in perfEntry)
    console.log("decodedBodySize = " + perfEntry.decodedBodySize);
  else
    console.log("decodedBodySize = NOT supported");

  if ("encodedBodySize" in perfEntry)
    console.log("encodedBodySize = " + perfEntry.encodedBodySize);
  else
    console.log("encodedBodySize = NOT supported");

  if ("transferSize" in perfEntry)
    console.log("transferSize = " + perfEntry.transferSize);
  else
    console.log("transferSize = NOT supported");
}
function check_PerformanceEntries() {
  // Use getEntriesByType() to just get the "resource" events
  var p = performance.getEntriesByType("resource");
  for (var i=0; i < p.length; i++) {
    log_sizes(p[i]);
  }
}
```